# Open Popup using Python after conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use a conditional statement ex:
`if(a>b)`

generate a popup saying a is the greater one.
Is it possible using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I found a solution:

```
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.

if(a>b):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Your text", "Your title", 1)
```